# Constrain collection of dependent types to match between args and return

Tags: idris, dependent-type

I want to write a function that takes in a collection (I'm not too fussed what kind) of dependent types, and returns another collection of the same types but perhaps with different values. The elements are of the form

```
data Tensor : (Vect r Nat) -> Type where
```

For example, a function that accepts a `(Tensor [2, 3, 4], Tensor [2], Tensor [])` or `(Tensor [3],)` and returns values of the same type.

**What I've tried**

- Using dependent pairs: accept a `List (s ** Tensor s)`. I don't then know how to constrain the output to have the same types.
- Using tuples, but I'm not sure how to fix the element type to be `Tensor`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that is indexed by the complete shape of all the `Tensor`s, not just any one of them. The shape of each `Tensor` is a `List Nat`, so the shape of a list of them is a `List (List Nat)`:

```
import Data.Vect 

data Tensor : (Vect r Nat) -> Type where

data Tensors : List (List Nat) -> Type where
  Nil : Tensors []
  Cons : Tensor (fromList ns) -> Tensors nss ->  Tensors (ns :: nss)
```

Here's an example of a shape-preserving `map` function:

```
mapTensors 
  : ({0 r : Nat} -> {0 ns : Vect r Nat} -> Tensor ns -> Tensor ns) -> 
  Tensors nss -> Tensors nss
mapTensors f Nil = Nil
mapTensors f (Cons t ts) = Cons (f t) (mapTensors f ts)
```